# Finding similar posts with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, search, pattern-matching

I have a table `posts`:

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
  id serial primary key,
  content text
);
```

When a user submits a post, how can I compare his post with the others and find similar posts?
I'm looking for something like StackOverflow does with the "Similar Questions".

Answer (score 5):

While [Text Search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-RANKING) is an option it is not meant for this type of search primarily. The typical use case would be to find words in a document based on dictionaries and stemming, not to compare *whole* documents.

I am sure StackOverflow has put some smarts into the similarity search, as this is **not a trivial matter**.

You can get *halfway* decent results with the [**similarity** function and operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgtrgm.html#AEN143897) provided by the [**pg_trgm**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgtrgm.html) module:

```
SELECT content, similarity(content, 'grand new title asking foo') AS sim_score
FROM   posts
WHERE  content  % 'grand new title asking foo'
ORDER  BY 2 DESC, content;
```

Be sure to have a [**GiST index**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgtrgm.html#AEN143969) on `content` for this.

But you'll probably have to do more. You could combine it with Text Search after identifying keywords in the new content ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Full Text Search in Postgres.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch-intro.html