# PostgreSQL: Find sentences closest to a given sentence

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, tf-idf, cosine-similarity

I have a table of images with sentence captions. Given a new sentence I want to find the images that best match it based on how close the new sentence is to the stored old sentences.

I know that I can use the `@@` operator with a `to_tsquery` but `tsquery` accepts specific words as queries.

One problem is I don't know how to convert the given sentence into a meaningful query. The sentence may have punctuation and numbers.

However, I also feel that some kind of cosine similarity thing is what I need but I don't know how to get that out of PostgresQL. I am using the latest GA version and am happy to use the development version if that would solve my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Full Text Search (FTS)

You could use `plainto_tsquery()` to ([per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-textsearch.html#TEXTSEARCH-FUNCTIONS-TABLE)) ...

> produce `tsquery` ignoring punctuation

```
SELECT plainto_tsquery('english', 'Sentence: with irrelevant words (and punctuation) in it.')

 plainto_tsquery
------------------
 'sentenc' & 'irrelev' & 'word' & 'punctuat'
```

Use it like:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  to_tsvector('english', sentence) @@ plainto_tsquery('english', 'My new sentence');
```

But that is still rather strict and only provides very limited tolerance for similarity.

#### Trigram similarity

Might be better suited to search for *similarity*, even overcome typos to some degree.

Install the additional module [**`pg_trgm`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgtrgm.html), create a GiST index and use the [similarity operator `%`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgtrgm.html#PGTRGM-OP-TABLE) in a **nearest neighbour search**:

Basically, with a trigram GiST index on `sentence`:

```
-- SELECT set_limit(0.3);  -- adjust tolerance if needed

SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  sentence % 'My new sentence'
ORDER  BY sentence <-> 'My new sentence'
LIMIT  10;
```

More:

- [Finding similar strings with PostgreSQL quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249635/finding-similar-strings-with-postgresql-quickly/11250001#11250001)
- [Finding similar posts with PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842196/finding-similar-posts-with-postgresql/17844292#17844292)
- [Slow fulltext search for terms with high occurence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/115162/3684)

#### Combine both

You can even combine FTS and trigram similarity:

- [PostgreSQL FTS and Trigram-similarity Query Optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/56232/3684)

Answer (score 1):

it's a pretty late answer, but I'm adding in case anyone encounters. If you add ": *" to the end of the words, it will bring up similar ones.
Sample:
JS autocomlete -> Codeigniter:

barcode = $ this-> input-> get ("term"). ":*";

Query:
$ query = 'select * from tablaneme where xx @@? LIMIT 15 ';
$ barcodequery = $ this-> db-> query ($ query, array (explode ("", $ barcode)))) -> result_array ();